# The "overlay_" function does not work in the field calculator

Tags: qgis

I want to create a dummy variable for whether the point geometry overlaps the polygon geometry, do you know why the following field calculator formula does not work?
I don't get any errors, but the results of the calculation are all blank.
I have tried other functions starting with "overlay_" with similar results.

```
CASE WHEN    
overlay_touches( 'buffer',limit:=1)=TRUE  THEN 1 
ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly because they do not touch like [this](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html):

[image]

Try `overlay_intersects` instead:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!
I forgot to mention that I was checking the intersection with the polygon layer with respect to the point layer, just as you did.
In the end, I did the calculation without "CASE WHEN" and it worked.
Does the " overlay_" function return TRUE/FALSE for "select by expression", and does it return a number for the field calculator?